# python.exe has stopped working, a problem caused the program stop working correctly

Tags: robotframework

While generating log.html from output.xml after execution of robot related tests, we are observing issue of python process getting hung and windows is suggesting to close the program

this is happening when executed on windows.help is required as we were not able to proceed.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete picture of your problem? A windows process getting stuck is a very broad description. You're unlikely to get any feedback without sufficient detail.

Comment: @Will Bickford.: ok i will provide some more data. we are executing a bunch of test cases using robot framework on a window system.once the cases are done, by using 'rebot' we are trying to generate log.html by using output.xml, there we are observing issue.if you need output.xml to check more, i will provide that as well. please let me know

Comment: Also, we are using below libraries in our framework.

Comment: can some one please come back one this issue. we were still stuck with it